# DNN - Redirecting specific file types

Tags: redirect, dotnetnuke

I've taken on the webmaster role for a website that uses DNN version 07.02.02. Most of the links to my pdf files are broken. They pdfs were in a folder called "/pdfs" now they're in a new folder "/docs/pdfs "

A few quick things:

1. I only have ftp access to the web site files. No access to web.config so rewrite rules are out.
2. I don't want to copy the old files back to "/pdfs" because it would mean managing two different pdf copies (there are over 500 pdfs).
3. Using file directories with a .pdf extension then add an index.asp file with a redirect i.e. "/pdfs/file_1001.pdf/index.asp" led to an error page because there's an override which doesn't allow site directory pages exposed.
4. Using a DNN module where I'd have to enter 500 files to redirect seems redundant when I only want to move a directory.

Any solutions to try?

Answer (score 0):

In DNN if you have HOST level access you can modify Config files through the Host/Configuration manager page.

There you could modify the web.config file.

You might also look at the siteurls.config file (also accessible there) in which you could define some URL rules, might be as easy as

```
<RewriterRule>
  <LookFor>/pdf/(.*)</LookFor>
  <SendTo>/docs/pdf/$1</SendTo>
</RewriterRule>
```

The above rule is completely untested, not positive if it will do what you need or not.

I did a little more testing, and it looks like this won't work out of the box as a default setting that tells it to NOT rewrite PDF files, but I can't find the source code for that currently.